# How to count specific word number in a certain length of string

Tags: c#

How to count a specific word in a specific length of a string. Let consider a string - 'Football is a great game It is most popular game all over the world It is not only a game but also a festival of get together for the nations which is most exciting too'. The total length of the string is 145. I like to count how many 'is' are in each 100 characters of the string.

Let consider the first part of the string having length 100, that is - 'Football is a great game It is most popular game all over the world It is not only a game but also '. Here we found 3 'is' in 100 characters. The rest portion of string is -'a festival of get together for the nations which is most exciting too' which is 69 in length and having 1 'is' in this length.

I can find out number of given word from a string but not from a specific length of string.Here is my code below -

```
string word = "is";
string sentence = "Football is a great game It is most popular game all over the world It is not only a game but also a festival of get together for the nations which is most exciting too";
int count = 0;
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(sentence, word, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
    count++;
}
Console.WriteLine("{0}" + " Found " + "{1}" + " Times", word, count);`
```

Input:

string - 'Football is a great game It is most popular game all over the world It is not only a game but also a festival of get together for the nations which is most exciting too'

Word - 'is'

In length - 100

Output:

In first portion: number of given word = 3

In second portion: number of given word = 1

Comment: Format your code.

Comment: Count total number of characters. group indexes by desired character count. Split original string based on indexes. perform match on each group of strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a substring with the desired length and then count using linq.

```
int length = 100;
string word = "is";
string sentence = "Football is a great game It is most popular game all over the world It is not only a game but also a festival of get together for the nations which is most exciting too";
//Substring with desired length
sentence = sentence.Substring(0, length);
int count = 0;
//creating an array of words
string[] words = sentence.Split(Convert.ToChar(" "));
//linq query
count = words.Where(x => x == word).Count();
Debug.WriteLine(count);
```

For the second portion create a substring starting at 100 to the end of your string.

Comment: No problem. As Nkosi pointed out its not the full solution. You need to add a loop to create portions of the desired length and the remainder.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
public class JavaApplication22 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Football is a great game It is most popular game all over the world It is not only a game but also a festival of get together for the nations which is most exciting too";
        String pattern = "is";
        int count = 0;
        int a = 0;

        while((a = str.indexOf(pattern, a)) != -1){
            a += pattern.length();
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("Count is : " + count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Although, method will work, but its java. And question was tagged as `C#`.